# Can we generate a report in Windows Service C#?

Tags: report

I have a Windows Service project in Visual Studio 2015 and i have data in a data table and i need to generate a report based on that data. I just want to know whether i can generate a report in windows service or not.

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed possible to generate a report on windows service c#. Using telerik reporting library,the Reportprocessor class will help you do all this ref: https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/t-telerik-reporting-processing-reportprocessor

Comment: Firstly Thanks for the suggestion. But is this Telerik library freely available and where will i find the downloadable reference library for the same.

Comment: unfortunately its not free.this is the link https://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx however there is a free trial if youd ike to evaluate before paying .